# How to set-up Linksys e4200 router on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: server, internet, router

How do I set up my router (Linksys e4200)? I have the software that came with it but it is for Windows. My computer has Internet access but when I click on Internet connection information I get error: `No valid active connections found`. I want to set-up the computer to be a server and I need the private IP address from my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This website](http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-setup-a-linksys-router.html) in the section of the webpage called **Linksys e4200 Setup** has step-by-step instructions for how to set up the Linksys e4200 router manually (without using the Windows installation CD) using the router's web interface at http://192.168.1.1/. To configure the Linksys e4200 router manually, start off with Step 1 and then skip Steps 2-6 and continue with Step 7 until the end of the instructions.

These are the instructions from the linked website with the Windows-specific steps 2-6 and other Windows-specific content removed.

1. Connect the Linksys e4200 router to a power source to turn on and wait for the device to power-up and go through its configuration steps. If choosing to manually configure the router or you do not have an installation CD, proceed to the next step.
2. Access the web-based configuration utility by entering 192.168.1.1 in your computer's web browser.
3. Enter "admin" for the router login, and "admin" for the password followed by clicking the "OK" menu button. A new password can be created for the router by selecting the "Administrative" and "Management" menu options from the primary configuration screen.
4. Select the "Setup" and "Basic Setup" menu options. Then select the "Language" to be used for the router.
5. Click the "Internet Setup" menu section and enter the connection specifics provided by your respective ISP or school (i.e. connection type, and if your host requires a static IP vice the default DHCP connection).
6. If connecting via DSL, find out if the ISP uses PPPoE, and if so select this option. Then, enter the username, password, and service name (if required) for your service.
7. Toggle the "Keep Alive" menu option to "Connect on Demand" if your ISP charges you for amount of time connected to the internet.
8. Select the "Wireless" and "Basic Wireless Settings" menu options.
9. Under configuration view, select "WiFi protected setup" to setup both the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks on the router (alternatively they can be manually configured).
10. Under the manual setup, choose which wireless standards to support under the 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz network options. Note, 802.11b and 802.11g devices cannot connect to the 5 GHz network, so ensure the appropriate options are selected on the 2.4 GHz network setup option. Typically, you want to ensure the lowest standard of connection in your home or apartment is supported on that network (i.e. if you have an old laptop, it may only be 802.11b compatible). The "Mixed" mode setting will support all standards (A through N).
11. Disable the SSID broadcast to keep the network name more secure, and if desired change the channel width and number assignments if you are an advanced user on this screen.
12. Select the "Wireless" and "Wireless Security" menu options to select between WEP, WPA Personal, WPA 2, WPA Mixed Mode, and WPA2 Personnel security standards on the network. Both the 2.4 and 5 GHz networks can use different security options if desired. WPA2 is the strongest security option available on this router if supported by all client devices.
13. Decide if you want to allow "Guest Access" to surf the Internet using the 2.4 GHz network or not. If you do, then the default option is to do so. If not, then select "Wireless" and "Guest Access" from the main router setup menu and change the default setting to "no."
14. Similar to the WRT54G setup, MAC address filtering can be enabled and configured on the e4200N router.
15. Configure advanced options as desired on the router that include network storage, parental controls (by device), VPN Passthrough, FTP Server, Firewall, (Choose Applications and Gaming from the main router setup menu) Gaming options, and (Choose Storage from the main menu) Media Server.
16. To enable network storage, a portable hard drive will need to be available to connect to the router. By default, all content on the disk will be accessible without a password. To disable this "feature", select "Storage" and "Administration" and then choose the "Disabled" menu option located under "Anonymous Disk Access". Shared folders can be used to manage network access to different contents stored on the disk with individual folders or the entire disk available to share. Linksys implements a group and user account policy located under the "Storage" and "Administrative" menu options.
17. Save settings and the network configurations will be complete.

Comment: The router is configured by my windows pc and i just want to set-up a server with my ubuntu pc

Comment: It seams i need some drivers or something installed on ubuntu

Comment: I runned the cd with wine on ubuntu and it dont find my internet hardware...

Comment: Most routers are plug and play. They don't need either a driver or an installation CD. Instead the Linksys e4200 router is enabled using the web interface at http://192.168.1.1/ It's not a website - it is actually the address of the Linksys e4200 router which forms the hub of a local network, and sometimes handles the Internet connection as well. So long as the cable is properly connected from the computer to the router, entering that in your web browser would take you to the router's web interface.

Comment: Do a hard reset on the router, perhaps? Most Linksys routers have a small reset button on them somewhere which, if pressed for 10 seconds or so, will reset the router to its factory defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Look in [the official manual](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/03/03b97504-d08c-45e6-bde2-88361df9eb63.pdf) for info about login via a browser, or perhaps try [this article](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/linksys-default-passwords/a/e4200-default-password.htm) first, may be faster.

Generally most customer grade routers provide a web interface, you may enter an IP address in the browser address bar, provide the credentials included in the manual (or sometimes even on a sticker on the bottom of the device) and configure (almost) everything there.

Comment: I know that, I think you did not understand the question, Pleae read it again. :|

Comment: The problem is that i get the error and i can't find the correct ip address to set-up the router in web interface...

Comment: I suppose if the router serves DHCP then you could check your IP addresss with `ip address show`, then lookup default gateway address with `ip route print` or `route -n` - it should be the router's LAN address.