# Setup Linksys E900 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, router, cisco

I just bought a Linksys E900 and I am unable to access the Admin Login page over http://192.168.1.1

Instead I see this page

[image]

There is no way I could login ad Admin and Setup the router.

Can anybody please help?

Thanks,

Shardul

Comment: It looks like it wants you to install the software which it is talking about so as you can control your router's settings from there, is there a problem you face with doing that?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and the accompanying CD has the software only for Windows and Mac. I came across similar issues (http://askubuntu.com/questions/338598/how-to-set-up-linksys-e4200-router-on-ubuntu-13-04) where the solutions talked about accessing 192.18.1.1 and I tried the same. The solutions also mentioned that there is not need to set up the software.

Comment: Have you tried using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) to get the software running on your machine?

Comment: Let me try it. Shall update you soon and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What about using the "Connect with an open and unsecured network" link on the page? Granted, it won't use https for connecting to the router admin setup, but on an internal network, not much of a security issue..

Comment: Well it worked..did start the Setup Software but again the software was unable to detect any Wireless Network Adapters on my machine and so it did not install. I have been using WiFi since a long time now on the same machine.

Comment: @douggro "Connect with an open and unsecured network" tries to take me to the internet and download the Router Setup Software.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to set up the Router using Ubuntu. The password to http://192.168.1.1 was not blank and was a random string.

I had to use a Windows machine to set it up. After it was setup, I was able to access it over http://192.168.1.1 from by Ubuntu Machine as well without the setup.

Thanks for all the help.

SB